# Necessary amount of countries in the model for 1 macro level predictor?

Tags: logistic, predictor

Within my logistic regression models I use cross-national data in order to say something about individual soft drug tolerance. In total I have 29 countries with 37.000 individuals. 
My supervisor wants me to find some theoretical fundament to the rule of thumb I have used (and she proposed), namely the fact that for every 10/15 countries 1 possible macro-level predictor can be included in the regression model. 
Can anybody provide me with this literature (and a reaction to this presumed rule of thumb). Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like a fun new game. We find or provide a justification, you report it and your supervisor publishes it? More seriously, it sounds as if you want to include country effects somehow in your model. That means more parameters, but you need to say much more about your intended model. I don't see how estimating more parameters itself justifies adding more predictors; if anything, quite the reverse. Conversely, what is positive is adding observations. One reference is Harrell, F.E. 2001. _Regression modeling strategies_. New York: Springer.

Comment: Thanks. The final model will consist of 4 explanatory macro-level variables and 9 explanatory micro-level variables. You're right about your 'reversed reasoning', but a similar rule of thumb (in order to exclude certain statistical bias) is not known ?

Comment: More please. First of all, macro- and micro-level are jargon in your field; please translate for the rest of us.  Second, how are countries to be represented? Fixed effects, random effects, indicator variables? What about interactions?

Comment: Macro= country-level variables: country-means, aggregated values of all citizens combined etc.    Micro= individual level; such as education, gender, tolerant personality etc.        There is one interaction (in the last model), and I do not use a multilevel model, so random/fixed effects do not seem to apply here.    I only want to know whether or not rules of thumb exist (as my supervisor boldly stated) because the less countries you include in the model; the less degrees of freedom; more biased results.   Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Sorry, my keyboard wasn't cooperating, I placed the reply by accident. See the previous , edited, post.

Comment: Thanks. It sounds as if different countries just appear in the model through their means or overall level of various predictors. If that's so, the model as such does not know how many countries are represented. Apart from that, why say that fewer countries means more bias? Bias depends on selection of countries, not the number of countries, as I see it.